# Sed Regex Error using \1

Tags: bash, sed

I keep getting the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 29: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS


grep -l 'someFiles' | xargs sed -r 's/<add fileName="\(.+?\)"/\1/g'
```

I am escaping the () as I have read to do in other files, I have also tried to work through it elsewhere:

https://regex101.com/r/tU9qV4/2

so I know my regex is working, I have also tested my grep, I am actually using a few exclusions and things in the statement, but it's outputting exactly what I need. Why am I still not able to use the \1?

Comment: No need to escape `\(` and `\)`. Since, you are using `-r [Extended RegEx]` option...Valid : `xargs sed -r 's/<add fileName="(.+?)"/\1/g'`

Comment: This is the solution, but Why not? Every last article I found said that sed in linux needed them?

Comment: In default BRE mode `(` and `)` need to be escaped but not in extended regex mode using `-r`. Besides `.+?` isn't supported in sed's regex engine

Comment: then what should I use instead of .+? I don't know how else I would collect all characters between " and "

Comment: You can use: `sed -r 's/<add fileName="([^"]*)"/\1/g'`

Comment: where can I find more about sed specific regex syntax?

Comment: not at regex101.com ;-) . The `sed` tutorial at http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/sed.html is probably more than you want, but if you make it all the way thru, you can call yourself a sed master. ( Do  you need to spend your time becoming a sed master?, That is a different Q ;-) ). Good luck.

Comment: These online regexp verification tools are the devil. Every tool has it's own regexp flavor it supports along with it's own additional caveats - you've got to write a regexp FOR THE SPECIFIC TOOL YOU PLAN TO USE. The fact that a given regexp "works" in any other tool, online or otherwise, is completely irrelevant.